# how to combine coefficients of a logistic regression model with existing prior knowledge about covariates?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, lasso, lars

I am working on developing statistical models for fault-localization.

on the one hand, i construct a logistic regression model with these considerations:
1-my dependent(response) variable is program execution status(failing or passing).
2-covariates are statements of the program.

after constructing this model, estimated coefficients are used to give a suspiciousness score to covariates(statements of the program).

on the other hand, i give a fault proneness score for each program statements which is based on its location on program code and some other code complexity metrics.

so, i have two knowledges about suspiciousness of each program statement which one of them is obtained from dynamic analysis(through regression analysis) and another from static analysis(fault proneness of different parts of the code according to program code complexity metrics).

my question is how can i combine these two knowledges about variables(covariates) to obtain my final suspiciousness scores of program statements?
thanks in advance.

**Note**: my prior knowledge about covariates is an importance factor in range [0-1] for each one. i would like to know how can i consider this knowledge in regression analysis. i want to consider this knowledge in a shrinkage regression like lasso with LARS method

Comment: You wan to incorporate prior knowledge? You should research bayesian inference.

Comment: @JoshW. my prior knowledge about covariates is an importance factor in range [0-1] for each one. i would like to know how can i consider this knowledge in regression analysis. i want to consider this knowledge in a shrinkage regression like lasso and with LARS method.